# Active Directory change password success message

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

We are resetting the Active Directory User password by connecting through LDAPS. We are also setting the "Change Password at next Logon" attribute.
When we Login to the Windows machine,we perform the following steps:

1. Login to the windows machine using the new password (**password 1**)
2. The machine prompts to change password
3. Enter the existing password (**password 1**) and a new password (**password 2**)

At this point we are expecting the message: `Your password has been changed.You will need to use the new password for future logins`.
However we receive the message: `Unknown user name or bad password`.
But, in the backend, the system has accepted the new password (**password 2**) as we are able to login using **password 2**.
What we are unable to understand as to why we are receiving the incorrect message when the system has accepted the new password
Do we need to set another attribute which will show the correct message?
Our code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
#########################
#This script resets the password in active user directory 
#########################

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAPS;
use Authen::SASL qw(Perl);
use Net::LDAP::Control::Paged;
use Time::Local;
use MIME::Lite;

my $CERTDIR     = "<certpath>";
my $AD_PASS     = "$CERTDIR/<certfile>";
my $sAN = $ARGV[0];
my $uninewpass;
my $mail;
my $fullname;
my $name;
my $distName;
my $finalresult;

### Generate Random Password ###
my $randompass = askPasswd();

### Reading Active directory connection credentials ###
my @AD_passwords = get_domain_pass();

###Reset password###
my $result = reset_AD_Password();


###SUB FUNCTIONS###

#Reset AD user password
sub reset_AD_Password {                              
    my $result = "fail";

    my $ad = Net::LDAPS->new($AD_passwords[0]);
    my $msg = $ad->bind(dn => "cn=$AD_passwords[2],$AD_passwords[1]",
                        password   => $AD_passwords[3],
                        version    => 3);

    if ($msg->code)
    {
            print "Error msg:" . $msg->error() . "\n";
            print "Error code:" . $msg->code() . "\n";
            exit 3;
    }

    my $acc_name            = 'sAMAccountName';
    my $acc_fullname        = 'displayName';
    my $acc_distName        = 'distinguishedName';
    my $acc_mail            = 'mail';

    my $act = $ad->search(
                        base    => "$AD_passwords[1]",
                        filter  => "(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=$sAN))",
                        attrs   => [$acc_name, $acc_fullname, $acc_distName, $acc_mail]);
    die 2 if ($act->count() !=1 );

    if ($act->code)
    {
            print "Error msg:" . $act->error() . "\n";
            print "Error code:" . $act->code() . "\n";
            exit 4;
    }

#Store DN for password reset
my $sANdn = $act->entry(0)->dn;

# Add quotes and uniCode to the passwords.
map { $uninewpass .= "$_\000" } split(//, "\"$randompass\"");
print "$uninewpass\n";

#Reset AD Password and change at next logon
my $rtn = $ad->modify($sANdn, replace => [ 'unicodePwd' => $uninewpass]);

if($rtn->{'resultCode'} != 0) {
    print "Error msg:" . $rtn->error() . "\n";
    print "Error code:" . $rtn->code() . "\n";
    exit 5;
}

#Change Password at next logon#
my $rtn = $ad->modify($sANdn, replace => { pwdLastSet => 0});

if($rtn->{'resultCode'} != 0) {
    print "Error msg:" . $rtn->error() . "\n";
    print "Error code:" . $rtn->code() . "\n";
    exit 6;
}
    $result = "pass";
    return $result;
}

###Generate password###
sub askPasswd {

        use String::Random;
        my $randPass = new String::Random;
        my $rndpassword = $randPass->randpattern("CCccn!cnC");

        print "Your random password is: " , $rndpassword , "\n";

        return $rndpassword;
}

###Read Credentials File###
sub get_domain_pass {
        open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $AD_PASS) or die "Could not open file";
        my $row = <$fh>;
        chomp $row;
        print "$row\n";
        my @AD_passwords = split/:/,$row;
        return @AD_passwords;
}
```

Comment: did you consider chomping some of those variables? it is difficult to test code as I do not have the same scenario, so stabbing in semi darkness here.

Comment: additionally, do you expect the `Your password has been changed.You will need to use the new password for future logins` message to come from AD?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard the perl code works just fine. It creates **password 1** correctly. Which variables are you suggesting `chomping`  And yes, we expect the `Your password has been changed.You will need to use the new password for future logins` message to come from AD when the user is prompted to change their password

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the root cause of the issue.
Our network has multiple AD servers. We were updating the password on one of the AD servers.
The sync between the AD servers takes some time in our network.
The user was logging on using a different AD server for verification. As this point, the sync had not taken place. Hence we were receiving the issue.
We have now modified the code to update the correct AD server based on which Ad server is used to authenticate the user.